# Can there only be one timeout in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, timer, settimeout

This code seems not to work... It shows the twCharCount element only once after a long time. Could it be that there can only be one timeout set? Any suggestions making this code better?
Thanks for any advice...

```
var timer = new Array();
var t=0;
var step=1000;
counter.hide();
var t =+ step;
timer[0] = setTimeout("$('#twCharCount').show()",t);
var t =+ step;
timer[1] = setTimeout("$('#twCharCount').hide()",t);
var t =+ step;
timer[2] = setTimeout("$('#twCharCount').show()",t);
var t =+ step;
timer[3] = setTimeout("$('#twCharCount').hide()",t);
var t =+ step;
timer[4] = setTimeout("$('#twCharCount').show()",t);
```

---

ok .. i'm sorry ... i kind of was not verry awake while writing this ...
of course im redecalring all the time ... this is why the all execute snychronously ...

Comment: There can be more than one timeout. You've got the + and = the wrong way round in the assignment operator and also there's no need to declare t with var again after the first declaration. Finally, use an anonymous function instead of passing a string to timeout, or pass a named function; you can cache the reference to the jQuery wrapped set outside of the named/anonymous functions

Comment: looks like you want to emulate a good old-fashioned completely deprecated `<blink>` thingy? Would there be a reason for it being deprecated then? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blink_element

Comment: Why are you recreating [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var intervalId = window.setInterval(function() {
    $('#twCharCount').toggle();
}, 1000);
```

and to stop blinking `window.clearInterval(intervalId);`.

Comment: @Shaz, nothing, it's just that `$('#twCharCount').show()` looked to me very much like jQuery code but of course I could be wrong here.

Comment: @Shaz `$('#twCharCount').show()` is not jQuery? It can't be more confusing then OP solution which is not working.

Answer (score 2):

Could it just be some syntax problems:

```
var timer = [];
var t=0;
var step=1000;
counter.hide();
t += step;
timer[0] = setTimeout("$('#twCharCount').show()", t);
t += step;
timer[1] = setTimeout("$('#twCharCount').hide()", t);
t += step;
timer[2] = setTimeout("$('#twCharCount').show()", t);
t += step;
timer[3] = setTimeout("$('#twCharCount').hide()", t);
t += step;
timer[4] = setTimeout("$('#twCharCount').show()", t);
```

`t =+step;` should be `t += step;`

and you shouldn't redeclare t over and over again.

Answer (score 1):

The code is wrong in many ways :(.
Your functions are all being called in the same time because their time (t) is the same.

if you want to increment `t`, you should probably not declare it on every acces (use `var t = ...` only once; after that you can access it by it's name : `t = ...`) and you should probably use `+=` instead of `=+`:
`a += b` is a shortcut to `a = a + b`, while `a =+ b` is a shortcut to `a = parseInt(b)`.
You probably wanted to write:

```
var timer = [];
var t=0;
var step=1000;
counter.hide();
t += step;
timer[0] = setTimeout("$('#twCharCount').show()", t);
t += step;
timer[1] = setTimeout("$('#twCharCount').hide()", t);
t += step;
timer[2] = setTimeout("$('#twCharCount').show()", t);
t += step;
timer[3] = setTimeout("$('#twCharCount').hide()", t);
t += step;
timer[4] = setTimeout("$('#twCharCount').show()", t);
```

One more thing, it is better to pass a function than a string as the first parameter for the `setTimeout` function:

```
setTimeout(function(){$('#twCharCount').show();},t);
```

Sry, but i can't help my self, this is the optimized code for you :

```
var timer = [],
step = 1000,
n = 4,
el = $('#twChartCount');
for(var i=0;i<n;i++)
    if(i%2)
        timer[i] = setTimeout(function(){el.hide();},i*step);
    else
        timer[i] = setTimeout(function(){el.show()},i*step);
```

Comment: Probably nothing... `=+` accomplishes no more than a simple assignment. Perhaps he tried `+=` and ran into problems because that isn't valid for initialization, but as you note the solution is to stop redeclaring the variable.

Answer (score 0):

There is virtually no limit on the number of active timeouts.

I don't see any real problems with your code. Probably the problem is not the timeout but the command you're executing.

Additional notes (not related to your question, but worth to say):

- You need the 'var' statement for a variable only once per function.
- instead of timer[...] I'd use timer.push() in this case
- you can use a single setInterval() instead

Answer (score 0):

```
var show = false;
window.setInterval(function() {
   if(show)
   {
      show = false;
      $('#twCharCount').show();
   }
   else
   {
      show = true;
      $('#twCharCount').hide();
   }
}, 1000);
```